# How to avoid the usage of a temporary byte array for loading the last 7 bits of 16 elements from a size_t array into a __m128i?

Tags: c, hashtable, sse, simd

For my hashmap implementation, I'm caching hashes for each map element in an array of length `NBUCKETS`, where each element corresponds to an element in the hashmap. Assuming a hash consists of 64-bits, the first 57 bits decide the position(bucket) in the hashmap and the last 7 bits (i.e `H2(hash)`) are used as control bytes for probing the table. More concretely, while finding an element in the map using linear probing, `H2(hash)` is compared for 16 elements at a time using SIMD intrinsics before comparing actual keys. Hence, each call to `probe_group()` probes 16 elements of the map at the same time.

But populating the `group` array with 16 elements from `hash_arr` is expensive. I want to avoid the usage of temporary `group` array and load the last 7 bits of 16 consecutive hash values from `hash_arr` directly into a `__m128i` (i.e `ctrl`).

Is there a way to directly load the last 7 bits of 16 hash values from `hash_arr` into `__m128i` instead of using the temporary byte array `group`?

```c
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NBUCKETS 100
#define GROUP_SIZE 16

typedef char h2_t;

// return the lowest byte 
static inline h2_t H2(size_t hash)
{
    return hash & 0x7f;
}

// If ith element in `group` is 'hash', then ith bit in `match` will be 1,
// otherwise it will be 0
static inline uint16_t probe_group(h2_t hash, h2_t *group)
{

    __m128i ctrl  = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) group);
    __m128i match = _mm_set1_epi8(hash);
    return _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(match, ctrl));
}

int main()
{
    size_t hash_arr[NBUCKETS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NBUCKETS; i++)
        hash_arr[i] = i;

    // TODO Optimize this: Avoid using this array. Instead load the last 7 bits of 16 hash values directly into a `__m128i`.
    const int start_pos = 90;
    h2_t group[GROUP_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < GROUP_SIZE; i++)
        group[i] = H2(hash_arr[(start_pos + i) % NBUCKETS]);

    // Element to be searched for in `group`.  ASCII for 'c' is 99
    h2_t find_ele = 'c';

    uint16_t match = probe_group(find_ele, group);

    for (int i = 0; i < GROUP_SIZE; i++) {
        if ((match >> i) & 1U)
            printf("Element at index %d in group is equal to %c\n", i, find_ele);
    }
}
```

Comment: Like cast it to a 128-bit integer (or even 64 bit) value and or in the remaining bits type operation?

Comment: So you need to do a strided load of 1 byte from the bottom of every 8 bytes?  You know you don't *have* to get 16 elements, you could only bother to shuffle together 4 or 8.  Do you need this to work with SSE2, or can you take advantage of SSSE3 `pshufb` or SSE4.1 `pblendvb`?  Unaligned loads + blend or mask+OR is probably good, especially if there can be only one match so you don't need to worry about which one's first.

Comment: You can hoist the `% NBUCKETS` by checking if you're close to the end of the array, and if not just going contiguous, or if you are then doing 2 parts at the end and start.

Comment: Does it have to work exactly like this, but optimized? This looks sort of like [swiss tables](https://abseil.io/about/design/swisstables), but they avoid having to gather bytes like this by storing the bottoms of the hashes packed.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the comment! I used it and it worked!

Comment: @harold Thanks for the comment! Later I realized a more cache-friendly way to approach this is to keep the bytes aligned. So now I store the last 8-bits of 16 hashes packed in a `__m128i` vector.